# NLTK ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

```
import nltk
text = nltk.word_tokenize("And now for something completely different")
nltk.pos_tag(text)
print(text)
```

Using the above code, I get the following error, apparently when trying to use the pos_tag function.
 I have Python3 32bit, and I installed NLTK from http://nltk.org/nltk3-alpha/ - the exe link.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python33\code\frenchPluralize.py", line 15, in <module>

    nltk.pos_tag(text)

  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\__init__.py", line 99, in pos_tag

    tagger = load(_POS_TAGGER)

  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 773, in load

    resource_val = pickle.load(opened_resource)

  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 137, in <module>

    from . import add_newdocs

  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>

    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc

  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>

    from .type_check import *

  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 8, in <module>

    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx

  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>

    from . import multiarray

ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 ni veljaven program Win32.
```

Comment: This usually means a 32 bit program is loading a 64 bit DLL, or vice versa. Take a look under Dependency Walker to find out which DLL is the wrong bitness.

Comment: Thank you, it seems it had to do with me failing to install numpy  correctly sometime ago.